# Question about "Royal Court"

Tags: terminology, definition

Someone asked me whether the term "royal court" could also mean the king's dukes, viscounts, barons, counts, earls, etc.  I know it contains his retinue, i.e. his advisors, servants, ministers, but does it also mean the entire nobility?  I'm not sure of this since I've never really studied monarchical hierarchy and terminology.  The definition of royal court on freedictionary.com is as follows:

> "The family and retinue of a sovereign or prince."

Definition No. 2b of "court" states:

> "The retinue of a sovereign, including the royal family and personal
>   servants, advisers, and ministers."

My question is simple: Can it ever include the nobility such as a duke or earl?  Is it different depending upon the monarchy? User3169 below has mentioned the "Royal Court of England".  Can an earl or duke or baron be a part of the "Royal Court of England"?  That would be a starter.

If anyone should know the answer to this, please inform me.  Thanks.

Comment: "royal court" written in lower case is a generalized noun, therefore it's meaning could vary from country to country. If you mean a specific one, for example the "Royal Court of England" (all caps) then it might be possible to answer, but you need to tell us which one.

Comment: How about both? I just want to know whether it's possible for the nobility such as dukes and counts, etc, to count as part of the royal court anywhere? and if so, then where? You can tell me what the Royal Court of England comprises.